# Erro no arquivo pom.xml do projeto

Tags: java-ee, maven, pom

Olá, estou com um problema que não consegui identificar, no meu projeto aparece um erro no arquivo pom.xml, já executei o Maven updte no projeto, mas o erro persiste, sendo que o meu repositório o .jar se encontra lá mas na hora do build ele não consegue identificar aparece a seguinte mensagem no overview do pom.xml.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o seu eclipse está a utilizando o repositório local que você diz ter o artefato: 
**Window -> Prefereces -> User Settings,** nesta tela verifique o caminho do Local Repository.

Outro possível problema, verifique seu repositório local do maven, o jar está instalado corretamente, possui pom?

Comment: Obrigado Ariel, sim já tinha configurado o settings do maven, mas eu identifiquei o erro, estava no arquivo _remote.repositories no repositório do aquivo .jar, eu deletei ele aí ele reconheceu o jar, eu acredito que estava dando conflito.